# How am I being hacked?

Tags: php, mysql, session

I have the following code in a file which, when variable `$action` equals a certain value, a message is added to the database and then an email is sent to the user advising them of the message. Simple.

Over the last couple of days there have been spam messages added to the database, and emails sent to users informing them of new messages. Not many and not all at once, just random times and content, but clearly spam.

I set the script so that if the `$from` variable does not equal 0 then don't proceed, but it seemed to bypass that somehow (all hack entries into db show `from_userid = 0`)

I am using cookies to check if a user is logged in - when a user logs in a cookie is set.

**QUESTIONS:** Is there somewhere I can look to see how I am being hacked, should I be using session instead of cookie, would this stop the file being accessed/hacked?

Heres the code:

```
// check a user logged in as soon as file accessed
if (!isset($_COOKIE['cookieName'])) { header("Location: /userlogin.html); }
```

Now check `$action` variable and proceed

```
$action = $_POST['action'];

if (($action=='contact') && ($_POST['from'])){ // AA

    require_once '/home/php/lib/setup.inc';
    require_once '/home/php/lib/dbconnect.inc';

    $from = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['from']);
    $to = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['to']);
    $from_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['from_name']);
    $body = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['body']);
    $reply_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['reply_id']);

    $body = nl2br($body);

    // add message to db

    if($from!='0'){ // BB

        $additem = mysql_query("
            insert into user_messages (
            from_userid,
            to_userid,
            from_name,
            message_contents,
            reply_to_id,
            msg_read
            )
            VALUES (
            '$from',
            '$to',
            '$from_name',
            '$body',
            '$reply_id',
            'No'
            )",$db
        );

        if(!$additem) { echo mysql_error(); exit; } // debug

        // send email notif for message
        $result20 = mysql_query("select name, emailaddr from users where (user_id = '$to')",$db);
        if(!$result20) { echo 'result error'; echo mysql_error(); exit; } // debug
        $databack20 = mysql_fetch_array($result20);
        $title = 'title';
        $currentdate = date("d");
        $month = date("m");    // "02"
        $currentmonth = date("F", mktime(0, 0, 0, $month)); 
        $currentyear = date("Y");
        $email = file_get_contents('/home/public_html/pages/html_email_templates/buddymessage.php');
        $email = str_replace(">name<","$from_name",$email);
        $email = str_replace(">name2<","$databack20[name]",$email);

        // setting Content-type header
        $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

        // Additional headers
        $headers .= 'From: siteName <info@siteName.com>' . "\r\n";

                    //send mail
        mail("$databack20[emailaddr]", "siteName Message", "$email", "$headers");

        $success = "Message sent to $databack20[name]";

    } // BB

} // AA
```

Comment: Is your from_userid field an INT field?

Comment: @bwoebi Yes, INT(11) - should I instead use if($from>0){ ... } ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems the real problem here is that anyone could submit any `POST` request, and you don't do a check to see if it's actually them. It's *really* easy to make a bot that does the following (and uses `00` in `from` instead of `0`, hence bypassing your "security" - I suggest casting to an int instead: `$from = (int)$from` and then checking `if ($from > 0)`, but this is not your real problem):

> POST http://www.domain.com/contact.php
> action=**contact**&
> from=**00**&
> body=**spam**&
> from_name=**spammer**&
> to=**1**
>
> POST http://www.domain.com/contact.php
> action=**contact**&
> from=**00**&
> body=**spam**&
> from_name=**spammer**&
> to=**2** <-- Increase forever in a loop

It could even be written in PHP as simple as the following:

```
<?php
    $curlHandle = curl_init();
    
    for ($i = 1; $i < 10000; $i++) {
        curl_setopt_array($curlHandle, array(
            CURLOPT_URL            => "http://www.domain.com/contact.php",
            CURLOPT_POST           => true,
            CURLOPT_COOKIE         => "cookieName: yep",
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => array(
                "action"    => "contact",
                "from"      => rand(1, 10000),
                "to"        => $i,
                "body"      => "Spam",
                "from_name" => "Spambot"
            )
        ));
        curl_exec($curlHandle);
    }
?>
```

so instead you should check using a `$_SESSION` cookie to see who it is from. Maybe also make a limit that one can only send a message every *nth* minute.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and more importantly, the explanation and example. Priceless!

Answer (score 0):

Without inside knowledge about the attacker's method, we are unable to directly answer the 'how' question. However, here are some steps that may help.

The `mysql_*` functions have been deprecated in PHP in favor of [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php). You should update your code to use PDO to take advantage of the new security features that it offers.

Additionally, verify that access to your database has not been compromised. You may need to check the database logs for unexpected login events.

In the meantime, while you are rewriting your code, consider replacing the following line with a more secure call to $_SESSION :

```
if (!isset($_COOKIE['cookieName'])) { header("Location: /userlogin.html); }
```

When you use this code, a malicious user can create a cookie to bypass your login requirement.

Comment: When you don't know some information, I'd ask first by a comment...

Comment: @bwoebi The OP doesn't have the information. That's the point of his/her post. This information will help to provide a workable solution even if it cannot provide an answer to the question asked in the title.

Comment: He has shown you his code? Then you may see his problem...?

Comment: @bwoebi With the code posted, we can answer the question "Does this code have insecurities?" It has several, and there are potentially other infrastructure issues that we cannot see. We cannot, however, answer the one that was really asked ("How am I being hacked?") which is the reason for the ambiguity in the first line of my response.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is when the attacker fills in there a non-integer value which is casted by the database to an integer: zero.

Check if `$from` is an integer:

```
if ($from > 0 && (string)((int)$from) === $from) { /* ... */ }
```

P.s.: you should really store the user data in a `$_SESSION` instead of giving the user the possibility to manipulate your hidden inputs.